# How could I disable caching, for specific php files?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, browser-cache

I am currently working on a WordPress powered ecommerce website, where the chosen shopping platform is WooCommerce.

Is there a way, without using a Plugin, which will allow me to prevent browsers from Caching certain php files?  In this instance, the 'header.php' and 'cart.php' files?  My assumption would be, that some tinkering to the '.htacess' file would be required but then I could be wrong.

Comment: What is the actual issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: The Contents of the Cart are being cached by the browser.  Consequently, preventing potential customers from removing products from their basket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue.  I completely overlooked/forgot, I had the below Caching Code in the `.htaccess` file.  School Boy error!

Once I removed the below code, the Basket Caching Problem was resolved.

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Should I discover a way to cache a website, without the Basket being Cached, I will add it to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with woocommerce, but generally you should just be able to add the following to the php files:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I tried your suggestion, as displayed, but to no success.  Should your suggestion be inside any specific tags?  I tried placing within `<?php [Code Here] ?>` but still to no success.